# Spring Boot 1.5.22 RELEASE and Spring framework 5.3.19 compatibility

Tags: spring, spring-boot

According to the [Spring boot 1.5.22 RELEASE documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.22.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements) it

> requires Java 7 and Spring Framework 4.3.25.RELEASE or above

Does the `above` mean that Spring framework 5.3.19 is supported as well?

Comment: No it isn't supported. SPring Boot versions are tied to certain Spring versions/ranges. And Spring Boot 1.5 is bound to 4.3 anything higher (or lower) will fail due to incompatibilities in the API etc.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thank you for your response. Are these details mentioned somewhere in documentation or this is the common approach?